# how to capture console output emitted by a jar file in a text area in javas-swing application

Tags: java, swing, jar

I want to capture console messages emitted by a jar file into jTestArea.

In a separate java application, I've used process to call a properly created jar file (using manifest). But the console messages are not being captured in jTextArea. The console output of System.out.println is being captured appropriately, however.

Seeking help.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to re-direct the output stream to the `JTextArea` as such :

```
JTextArea log = new JTextArea();
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new CustomOutputStream(log));
System.setOut(printStream);
System.setErr(printStream);
```

You should keep a reference to the original output streams if you want to re-direct it back to the console however:

```
PrintStream standardOut = System.out;
PrintStream standardErr = System.err;
```

And the simple implementation of `CustomOutputStream`:

```
public class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public CustomOutputStream(JTextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        textArea.append(String.valueOf((char)b));
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }
}
```

[Source article](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/redirect-standard-output-streams-to-jtextarea)

Although you should be aware that `System.out.println()` is buffered and therefore your output may not be displayed as soon as you would like.

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed. I'm new to Java and not really being able to manifest how this small application would be incorporated with a jar file in main() function. Can you please help me with the full code using main() function too?

Comment: @sameeroak There is a small example program in the web link posted in my answer.

Comment: I referred to the same exact program before I posted the question here. The thing is the code works perfect, however, when usded S.o.p in the same code. I've a jar file which I'm invoking through another application. All S.o.p are working perfectly and sending the output to the textarea. However, console output of the jar which I'm using is not being sent to the textarea.

Comment: I guess I have found the problem. I'm using Process for executing the jar file. Correct me if I'm wrong, but there doesn't seem to be other way than using Process for this purpose. Since it's a new process altogether, the textarea created is not in its process-space. Is there a way to execute a jar file in the same main process without having created a new process using Process?